# SVM predict method

Tags: android, opencv, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

CAn anyone help me about the method SVM predict of Opencv on Android, because when i call it, it gives me a results, but i can't have the distance between train set and test set for calculating the confidence value.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.
Marco

Answer (score 1):

well you can try setting the DFValue to true i.e. as the signature states below it is false by default.

```
float CvSVM::predict(const CvMat* sample, bool returnDFVal=false )
```